# Regular expression required for valid domain name check in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression which will check the domain name including characters like 
a-z A-Z 0-9 -

Also does any domain name having underscore _ character?

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`?

Comment: no I did not. But working on one scenario where we should not allow domain name like www.platform.com/test. /test or ?test should not be allowed at all.

Comment: I meant to say there should be only domain name or domain name with subdomain. No other parts are allowed.

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL does NOT do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what youre searching for:

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)?.(com|org|net|mil|edu|de|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU|DE)$

Comment: I guess it will not work as extension could be anything like .in or .co.in. I just wanted to make sure there should not be any slashes or any unwanted character. Only domain name should be there.

Comment: there are about 250 other top level domains

Comment: and you can add `i` modifier to your regex to prevent duplication!

Comment: Even more than that, with the advent of .companyname and similar TLDs. Having a whitelist of acceptable TLDs is never gonna work...

Comment: @UmeshKulkarni: I feel using the above answers as a base, you should be able to work this up.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression would work on any number of subdomains and all top level domains (the world is not just murka):

```
/^ (?: [a-z0-9] (?:[a-z0-9\-]* [a-z0-9])? \. )*  #Subdomains
   [a-z0-9] (?:[a-z0-9\-]* [a-z0-9])?            #Domain
   \. [a-z]{2,6} $                               #Top-level domain
/ix
```

Domain names cannot have underscores. Only [a-zA-Z0-9], as well as hyphens if they are not at the beginning or the end of a subdomain name.

Comment: DOMAIN names CAN have underscores.  HOST NAMES can't.  There is a difference and he is most likely worried about host names but I just thought I should point this out.

Comment: What DOMAIN name can have underscore?  I tried this..I went to godaddy, tried searching for e_s.com and it corrected it to es.com.  Then, went into cPanel to try to add a subdomain with _, and it said it was invalid.  Trying to figure out what DOMAIN name can have underscore?  Are you referring to what comes after the /?  Just trying to figure this out.  Sorry to bring this back up.  This post was helpful to me, so wanted to double check what you were referring to.